# How to find most popular person in GitHub?

Tags: github, github-api

For example:

- Person who having most followers
- Person who having most repos
- person whose total repos having most stars

Comment: @JamieKeeling I want to search most popular repos,finding these repos' authors,then search these author's all repos,then these repos' stargazers,then all stargazers' repos,then all stargazers' repos' repos.......Till some degree limitation

Comment: You've misunderstood my comment. What have you tried yourself so far? Add a snippet of code to demonstrate what you've tried and then we can  advise on what you need to correct.

Comment: @JamieKeeling I havn't tried,but I want to use the method I mentioned,do you have a better method or algorithm?

Comment: Or you can play with the results in this little open source project: http://githubstats.lip.is

Comment: Why isn't this off-topic?

Answer (score 41):

Github search has provided such function,it's Linus Torvalds:
[most followers](https://github.com/search?o=desc&q=followers%3A%3E%3D1000&ref=searchresults&s=followers&type=Users)

Answer (score 9):

Top GitHub developers worldwide (by language, location):

- http://git-awards.com/users

More specific inquiries are possible via SQL queries to the GitHub data on BigQuery:

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/public-data/github

Answer (score 5):

To view the Persons with ost stars or repo,
on a DAILY BASIS,

https://github.com/trending

Comment: It's just trending about hot repos or developers,not marked with most stars~

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of API request to GitHub to get the latest data with users having the highest number of followers sorted in descending order by this query.

https://api.github.com/search/users?q=followers%3A%3E%3D1000&ref=searchresults&s=followers&type=Users

Answer (score 0):

This repository lists top users by country based on public contributions, total contributions and total number of follower. Go to [top-github-users](https://github.com/gayanvoice/top-github-users).

It generates a map that shows density of total public contributions by country
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqtwB.png). Go to the map [link](https://gayanvoice.github.io/top-github-users/index.html).